# Route IP Packets with Same Source and Dest IP

Tags: networking, ip, routing, iptables

I am hand-crafting ethernet packets using `socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_IP))`, and have successfully sent UDP packets from my PC to my router this way. Using `tcpdump` on both ends, I can see that the PC sends out a packet with the intended contents, and the router receives it. Specifically, I am using the following command to watch for my constructed packets with `source port = 0` and `dest port = 34567`: `sudo tcpdump -i any -e -x udp port 34567 -vvv`

I am seeing some unexpected behavior, however, depending on what I put in the source and dest IPs in the v4 header. Specifically, if I set the source and dest IP both to the PC address, I see the outbound packet on the PC, but I don't see any message on the router that the nic received it. If I set `source = <pc>` and `dest = <router>` I see a message (obviously), and if I set `source = 0.0.0.0` and `dest = <pc>`, I see the message, too. But in no cases does the router send the packet back to the PC.

So my questions are:

1. Why does having `source = dest = <pc>` in the IPv4 header prevent `tcpdump` from showing the packet?
2. Why isn't my router forwarding on the packet with `dest = <pc>`? Note that I tried adding an iptables rule `-A FORWARD -i enp2s0 -o enp2s0 -j ACCEPT` where `enp2s0` is my LAN-connected nic, but it didn't help.

For additional context, see my earlier question: [Route Local-Interface-Destined Packets to Gateway](https://superuser.com/questions/1566913/route-local-interface-destined-packets-to-gateway)

Comment: On modern networking equipment using switches and modern network cards, that traffic will never actually pass to the wire. it just does a hard u-turn when it gets to the nic. even if this wasn't the case, your switch memorizes the ports that MAC addresses can be reached through, so at most the traffic would go to the switch, the switch would see that the frame is destined to go back the same way it came, and it would never route the packet itself (switches operate primarily below the IP layer, so they don't know routers from a hole in the ground).

Comment: @FrankThomas That was my experience using raw raw IP-layer packets - they weren't even leaving the NIC. That's why I switched to using Ethernet layer packets. For all of the packets in my question, the source and dest MAC addresses are the PC and router nics, respectively, so the switches route them properly. The IPv4 source and dest are the fields I'm experimenting with.

Comment: @FrankThomas: Yes but tcpdump does not read from the wire; it doesn't even read from the _NIC_, either. It reads everything from the kernel's network stack (afaik using the same kind of raw sockets as OP is using).

Comment: @user1686 Note I *am* seeing the packet come through on the router. I'd like to understand why it's not forwarding it on, and why in certain cases the router doesn't see it.

Answer (score 1):

I was finally able to get it to work. There were a number of reasons things weren't getting through:

1. Setting the source and dest IP to the same value in the IPv4 header is apparently classified as a [LAND Attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAND). While the specific packet I crafted wouldn't trigger DOS (since it demands no reply), I suspect something deep in the linux kernel is dropping the packet before it even gets to `tcpdump`. I was able to work around it by spoofing a public IP.
2. My router `FORWARD` chain only had rules for LAN>WAN and WAN>LAN. Adding a new `ACCEPT` rule for LAN>LAN allowed the packet to be sent back to the PC.
3. My PC `INPUT` chain allowing `ESTABLISHED`/`RELATED` packets, but because of the address spoofing, the firewall did not classify the forwarded packet as `NEW`, even though it was just sent as an outgoing packet. Adding a new rule to explicitly `ACCEPT` the packet fixed it.

Proof for posterity:

```
Hello, Raw!
Listening on port 34567 (0x8707)
Building ethernet packet with 64 bytes comprised of headers of size 14 (ETH) + 20 (IP) + 8 (UDP)
Interface eno1 at index 2
Interface eno1 has mac <redacted>
Sent 64 bytes:
 <redacted> 08 00
 45 00 00 32 00 00 00 00 40 11 B4 BE <redacted> C0 A8 03 53
 00 00 87 07 00 0C 08 61
 3F 4F 6B 21 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
Server successfully read message from client: [?Ok!]
```